# Help me identify this audio connector on a turntable

Tags: audio, wire, vintage

I have recently purchased a West German NECKERMAN 830 record player (1960s), which requires a separate set of speakers for audio output. Could somebody tell me the technical name for this cable so that I can purchase the correct counterpart?

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to post another photograph, straight-on to the socket, showing the pins.I can't quite see into the end. I *think* there was a plug which had a small plastic peg sticking out, but otherwise looked like a 5-pin DIN.

Comment: The connection is to an amplifier, not directly to speakers : DIN speaker plugs had 2 much beefier pins, with a separate plug for each channel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a 5pin [DIN plug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector)

[image]

http://elektrotanya.com/philips_n4506.pdf/download.html

http://www.ebay.com/bhp/bang-olufsen-din

http://www.leadsdirect.co.uk/technical-library/pinouts-wiring-diagrams/din-midi-wiring/

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, it's a 5-pin DIN connector.

This will carry the audio signals from the pickup cartridge to a separate amplifier with a 'phono' input. The signal levels are very low (because it's generated by the needle wiggling in the record groove) and the bass frequencies need to be boosted.* Stereo amplifiers of the period were all fitted with phono pre-amplifiers to do this. You may need to purchase a separate phono preamp to boost the signal to AUX IN levels on a modern hi-fi.

```
Pinout 
1 Left +
4 Left - 
2 Ground
5 Right -
3 Right +
```

The DIN plugs were common on German equipment. Phono plugs were more common on American and Japanese products. You may need to cut the DIN plug off ane solder on some phone plugs.

```
Phone Plug Left
Tip: Left +
Sleeve: Left - and half the ground wire strands.

Phono Plug Right
Tip: Right +
Sleeve: Right - and half the ground wire strands.
```

- The signal levels and frequency response were defined by the RIAA standard. You should see this referenced in any decent preamp.

Comment: More specifically, DIN plugs were standard on German equipment : DIN stands for Deutsche Industrie Normen" or "German Industry Standards".

Answer (score 1):

It's a 5-pin DIN connector, probably a 180 degree version (i.e. 45 degrees between each of pins)

The corresponding socket was often found on cassette recorders of the same vintage, and the output levels will either be "phono" (very low) or less likely "line" (low) and insufficient to drive speakers without a separate amplifier.